# Copy db from xampp files, sytem not working

Tags: xampp

I have a question. My windows system stopped working and I would like to copy db data from xampp who was intalled on this system. I have only xampp files. Is it possible  ?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copy complete XAMPP directory to another working Windows system and try to launch it as usual. Or, you can try to backup current xampp directory, reinstall xampp somewhere else, and then overwrite it with your backup.